# How to make a pivot table that can filter week and month from dates in horizontal?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am so confused with the pivot table options. I have used it before but I am not getting the desired results.

My table looks like this
[image]

What I need is to make a pivot table that will show names in the first column and then show the sum of numbers grouped by month in columns.
For example:

```
Name        7       8         <-----Months
Oliva M     30      30        <-----Sum of the 1s in the row
Eboni Sh    30      30
Stefanie    25      12
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just use countifs() and perhaps unique() to get a list of the names.

Comment: Your data is not suitable for a pivot table.  Pivot tables are meant to work with normalized data, like name, date, value (each observation on a new line).  It is not meant to recast cross-tabs into other tabular  forms.